# Storing content and assigning to named zone in Orchard 1.4

Tags: orchardcms

After reading the documentation for some time, either I'm missing something or I'm still below the level that the docs are aimed at.

I have a layout with two zones defined in the content area - Model.Content and Model.Sidebar.

I can create pages and assign content to Model.Content (the Body on the page seems to be automatically assigned to Model.Content) - how do I assign content to the Model.Sidebar zone from the page content editor, same as the Body & Model.Content?

All of the documentation I have read seems to imply that this is rather more complicated than I think it should be - I hope to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Content goes into local zones within the global Content zone. There are ways to send rendering to other zones but it's complicated right now. You could use widget for that but it's not very clean, or you could code: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/03/26/dispatching-orchard-shapes-to-arbitrary-zones.aspx There is also a module called Origami that may help.

We have a feature scheduled for Orchard 1.5 to allow placement of shapes into arbitrary zones.

Comment: So what you are saying is that right now there is no way to have multiple content areas with arbitrary content in them without a lot of hassle?  In the mean time, would dropping to the html view in the Page content editor allow me to essentially achieve what I want directly? (eg I would remove the Model.Sidebar zone and instead just do it with floated divs in the content editor for each page - nowhere near ideal, but...)

Comment: The link you give seems vast overkill for what I need :(  It seems odd that I can only have one body of content for each page.

Comment: No, that's not what I said. I gave you three different ways you could do it. Here's a fourth: use text fields and configure them to contain html. That will give you multiple bodies of contents. I do not understand what you mean by "dropping to the html view in the page content editor".

Comment: Moo, the link Bertrand gave is not overkill. It's 1 line of code more than what would normally go into the Content Part's Driver class.

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't give me three different ways, you did exactly what the Orchard docs do and mention something without really explaining it - and that's my problem I think.  The Orchard docs really aren't aimed at a new user of the system, there is quite a steep learning curve.  Anything prefixed with "it's complicated right now" or "it's messy" isn't an actual solution, it's a hack, which is why I responded as I did.  I've tried using text fields but they are getting displayed in the same zone as the main content body - I can't find any decent docs on how to display them elsewhere.

Comment: Giscard, it certainly is overkill because having multiple content areas per page is a basic requirement of a CMS - I shouldn't have to drop to code and modify a driver to accomplish it, because that raises other issues.  I'm a decent coder, that's not the problem, the problem is having to do it that way.

Comment: My main issue here seems to be the over complicated nature of the orchard docs - topics are introduced, quickly skipped over and huge chunks of things are left vague for the new user.  Fantastic.

Comment: What's fantastic is people complaining about open source. The docs, like the rest of the software, is written by the community. If you're not satisfied with it, improve it. If you're just here to complain about something you haven't and have no intention of contributing anything to, well, I think you should probably not use the software and find something else.
Sorry for trying to help.